# Minecraft crashing after replacing skin file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to change my skin so I replaced steve.png, but now when I join a world it crashes. Here's the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// There are four lights!

Time: 11/24/20, 2:00 AM
Description: Registering texture

java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for assets/minecraft/textures/entity/steve.png
    at java.base/sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at dgw.a(SourceFile:87)
    at dgs.a(SourceFile:97)
    at dgs.a(SourceFile:90)
    at elr$a.a(SourceFile:82)
    at elr.b(SourceFile:57)
    at elr.a(SourceFile:28)
    at elw.b(SourceFile:85)
    at elw.a(SourceFile:68)
    at elw.d(SourceFile:61)
    at elw.a(SourceFile:51)
    at ebv.a(SourceFile:297)
    at ebv.a(SourceFile:414)
    at ebv.a(SourceFile:395)
    at ebs.a(SourceFile:477)
    at ebs.a(SourceFile:743)
    at ebs.a(SourceFile:540)
    at dlx.e(SourceFile:1021)
    at dlx.e(SourceFile:654)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:215)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at java.base/sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at dgw.a(SourceFile:87)
    at dgs.a(SourceFile:97)
    at dgs.a(SourceFile:90)
    at elr$a.a(SourceFile:82)
    at elr.b(SourceFile:57)
    at elr.a(SourceFile:28)
-- Resource location being registered --
Details:
    Resource location: minecraft:textures/entity/steve.png
    Texture object class: elr
Stacktrace:
    at elw.b(SourceFile:85)
    at elw.a(SourceFile:68)
    at elw.d(SourceFile:61)
    at elw.a(SourceFile:51)
    at ebv.a(SourceFile:297)
    at ebv.a(SourceFile:414)
    at ebv.a(SourceFile:395)
    at ebs.a(SourceFile:477)
    at ebs.a(SourceFile:743)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    All players: 1 total; [ebf['DerKaiser4709'/104, l='ClientLevel', x=304.75, y=4.00, z=1304.63]]
    Chunk stats: Client Chunk Cache: 225, 121
    Level dimension: minecraft:overworld
    Level spawn location: World: (241,5,1281), Chunk: (at 1,0,1 in 15,80; contains blocks 240,0,1280 to 255,255,1295), Region: (0,2; contains chunks 0,64 to 31,95, blocks 0,0,1024 to 511,255,1535)
    Level time: 104635 game time, 104635 day time
    Server brand: vanilla
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at dym.a(SourceFile:449)
    at dlx.c(SourceFile:2181)
    at dlx.e(SourceFile:672)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:215)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.16
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.16
    Operating System: Linux (aarch64) version 10
    Java Version: 9-internal, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 357053488 bytes (340 MB) / 838860800 bytes (800 MB) up to 838860800 bytes (800 MB)
    CPUs: 8
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -Xms768m -Xmx800m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    Launched Version: 1.16
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.3 build 13
    Backend API: GL4ES wrapper GL version 2.1 gl4es wrapper 1.1.5, ptitSeb
    GL Caps: Using framebuffer using ARB_framebuffer_object extension
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    CPU: 9x null
```

Comment: It says "java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for assets/minecraft/textures/entity/steve.png". You didn't change the skin properly. Can you look on the internet how?

Answer (score 4):

This is not how one changes the player skin. Repair your install (recover steve.png where it was), then go to https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/profile/skin then log in and upload your new skin.